# If ActiveSheet to loop through and select sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook that simulates an in-house program. There are two macros; one goes "forward" and one goes "backwards" to create a loop moving users to each visible sheet. For example,

Sheet 1->Sheet 10->Sheet 11->Sheet 1.

There are hidden sheets used as templates.

```
Sub Forward()
idx = ActiveSheet.Index
If Sheets(idx + 1).Visible = False Then
Sheets("Name Sequence").Select
Else
ActiveSheet.Next.Activate
End If
End Sub

Sub Backward()
If ActiveSheet Is Sheets(1) Then
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count).Activate
Else
ActiveSheet.Previous.Activate
End If
End Sub
```

The intent is to have the macros cycle through and select visible sheets, moving the user to a different sheet each time they click the forward or backwards buttons.

Comment: Store the sheets in an array and increment that?

Comment: Users are free to make as many copies of the hidden templates as they would like. The macro needs to be able to loop through the visible copies. 

Clicking "Forward" with the last visible sheet selected would take you back to "Name Sequence" which is always the first visible sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Select Next or Previous Visible Sheet

```vb
Sub Forward()

    Dim ash As Object: Set ash = ActiveSheet
    
    If ash Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "There is no active sheet.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim aIndex As Long: aIndex = ash.Index
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ash.Parent
    Dim shCount As Long: shCount = wb.Sheets.Count
    
    Dim nsh As Object
    Dim n As Long
    
    If aIndex < shCount Then
        For n = aIndex + 1 To shCount
            Set nsh = wb.Sheets(n)
            If nsh.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then nsh.Select: Exit Sub
        Next n
    End If
    
    For n = 1 To aIndex - 1
        Set nsh = wb.Sheets(n)
        If nsh.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then nsh.Select: Exit Sub
    Next n

    MsgBox "This is the only visible sheet.", vbExclamation
    
End Sub

    
Sub Backward()

    Dim ash As Object: Set ash = ActiveSheet
    
    If ash Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "There is no active sheet.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim aIndex As Long: aIndex = ash.Index
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ash.Parent
    Dim shCount As Long: shCount = wb.Sheets.Count
    
    Dim psh As Object
    Dim p As Long
    
    If aIndex > 1 Then
        For p = aIndex - 1 To 1 Step -1
            Set psh = wb.Sheets(p)
            If psh.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then psh.Select: Exit Sub
        Next p
    End If
    
    For p = shCount To aIndex + 1 Step -1
        Set psh = wb.Sheets(p)
        If psh.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then psh.Select: Exit Sub
    Next p
    
    MsgBox "This is the only visible sheet.", vbExclamation
    
End Sub
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you! 

This is going into a collaborative project. I found out the wrong macro had been assigned to one of the buttons on one of the template pages and that was causing issues moving around the workbook.